# Работа с подменю в битриксе

Tags: битрикс

Добрый день! Я начинающий разработчик битрикс, столкнулся с такой проблемой. Заказчик поставил задачу чтобы меню можно было редактировать в админке или прямо на сайте под администратором. Ситуация такая есть верхнее меню двухуровневое и левое меню двухуровневое, так вот при редактировании пунктов меню в визуальном режиме, менеджер видит только пункты меню первого уровня. Как сделать чтобы редактирование было возможно всех подменюшек?

Меню выглядит так:
[image]

А когда редактируешь его через админку или на панели управления, там только два последних пункта выводятся:

[image]

Где скрываются остальные пункты меню? Хотя это один компонент, и некоторые пункты меню содержат подменю еще, но их тоже нигде редактировать нельзя.

Answer (score 1):

нужно заходить в каждый раздел и оттуда редактировать.. 
но есть готовое решение.
http://marketplace.1c-bitrix.ru/solutions/intervolga.menu/